# Do search engines crawl JavaScript generated pages?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, javascript

I'm considering building a new website using react.js and am doing quite a bit of research before embarking into anything.

I have found quite a few articles stating that websites that have content generated through JavaScript frameworks (Such as React, Angular, Vue) cannot be crawled and indexed by certain search engines (like Bing, Yahoo, Duck Duck Go, etc).

SEO being very important, this is quite concerning to me. However, I have also noticed that all these articles date from 2018 and earlier.

Does someone have any up-to-date information on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SEO is an important topic - i wouldn't recommend to use Javascript-based content loading.

Javascript-rendered pages ignore the basic paradigm of internet, used freely by Googlebot too. URL, unique resource locator, has no validity at Javascript-rendered sites. At Javascript-rendered sites any resource may have the same URL.

But, Googlebot needs an unique URL for crawling and indexing. That is why Javascript-rendered sites make heavy use of fallback techniques, like History API, server side pre-rendering and so on - with a single purpose - to make a document show to Googlebot a unique address, while it natively doesn't have one.

Frameworks for creation of Javascript-rendered sites, all the React, Angular, Vue and gazillion of similar, were invented for purposes, where proper content indexing wasn't a question, so-called SPAs, single page applications, like GMail. But, later hipster misappropriate these techniques and methods and began making everything with frameworks, invented for absolutely another things.

In my opinion, SLA frameworks should be used only for purposes, where indexing is not a task. And vise versa, where you care about indexing - use any technique, which creates native URL for each document.

Comment: Very interesting and helpful answer @Evgeniy. Definitely food for thought. What would you think of a React website that compiles its JavaScript on the server-side? Then the client would only receive HTML. Would that perform better?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/fix-search-javascript ++ https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html ++ https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering

Comment: Very interesting documentation nikant. Although it is helpful, the major problem seems to lie with other search engines, not so much Google.